# Webview vs hybrid apps

Tags: android, ios, webview, cross-platform, hybrid-mobile-app

I've been reading a lot of articles talking about native apps, hybrid apps, webviews. I feel like the term "hybrid" and "webview" are used interchangeably.

There are websites where i read saying webview is basically a native app except you have section of the layout called a "webview" and it can load websites or sections of websites on it. (android uses the `WebView` class and ios uses the `WKWebView` class)

Then there are other articles that explain hybrid apps "use web technology such as webviews...." then it goes on to say examples of hybrid technologies are like React Native, xamarin, flutter, etc...

I'm just really confused. When people say their app uses "Webviews" are they referring to android's and ios's respective Webview classes? Or are they talking about their app uses react native, flutter or something else??

Answer (score 1):

making it simple - a native app having webview can load websites on it, so it's possible to develop a mobile's website that can be used by your android/ios app using that. You could call it a webview app then.
However, even though react native can use webview technology under the hood it is not usual to refer to hybrid apps as a "webview apps"

Answer (score 0):

If a people says that is using 'WebView', it mean that they're using WebView classes not flutter and etc, altrought one not exclude the other.

Is more easy to ask what de `projectist doing.`